# How to avoid duplicating work related to the same issue in GitHub?

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and I am wondering how people manage to avoid working on the same issue in GitHub. If there is an open issue and person A and B try to solve it simultaneously, then it looks a waste of time since another person could have worked on a different issue. Can somebody explain it to me how this is done in GitHub? Should we simply comment in an issue that we are the one going to work on it?
I have the same question about adding new features? If I am extending the capabilities of a method or function used say in `scikit-image`, how can I know I am the only one working on this?

Answer (score 1):

Most larger (and not only that) projects have a wiki, a mailing list or an owner. Contact those.

In the end, if several solutions pour in, even better: the best can be selected, or they can be combined.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to assign the issue to the person working on it.  For example, if I plan to work on an issue, I'll assign it to myself, and then everyone can see who's working on it.

If you're on a project where you can't assign issues to yourself because you lack permissions, it's usually just fine to say, "I'm looking into this issue," and then respond back if you don't intend to work on it further.